# How to make htlatex split large html file into sub-documents

Tags: tex4ht

I've used HEVEA and HACHA in the past to make web-pages from TEX sources.  The result is a separate web page for each \section{} of the original manuscript.

My latest manuscripts are more complex and HEVEA can't cut it.  However, using HTLATEX, I can convert the manuscript to a single webpage.

Is there any way to get HTLATEX to automagically split the output into sub-documents for easier navigation?

Comment: I found the answer at [CTAN][1].  Apparently I needed to include the command-line parameter 

    `htlatex source.tex "html,3,next"`

Not sure what the 3 means.. but lower numbers did not produce the sub-documents.

  [1]: http://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb25-1/gurari.pdf

Comment: Could you please turn this into an answer and self-accept it (after the waiting period) so that question is officially concluded. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer at [TUG](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb25-1), contributed by Eitan Gurari in his presentation entitled TeX4ht: HTML production.

I needed to include the command-line parameter htlatex source.tex "html,3,next".(PS The 3 has to do with the subsection depth at which htlatex stops generating HTML.)

Comment: Would you show precisely the command line?

Comment: @egreg my file name is journal.tex, so I would enter: `htlatex journal.tex "html,3,next"`

Comment: For further clarification, inside journal.tex, I have my usual LaTeX syntax which htlatex will render into a webpage. If I want htlatex to generate a link to a new page for a section of the content, I cut and paste the content to a new file called, let's say, howtolink.tex.  To create the link, I add the code: `\section{How To Link\label{howtolink}}` (this goes in journal.tex where the original content was cut from).  HTLATEX interprets  the label as a command to render howtolink.tex to a separate html document.

Comment: One additional correction: you must also input howtolink.tex into journal.tex.  This is done by adding the line `\input{howtolink}` to journal.tex on the line immediately following the section title.