# make4ht: allowing the build process to continue when parsing fails

Tags: lua, make4ht

I use [make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht) to produce html; part of the process is a custom build file that parses the `HTML` and does some checking/operations:

### `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test: $2^3$

unbalanced: ($6)$

\section{test section}
more text
\end{document}
```

### `mwe.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,next,5,-css,NoFonts}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

### `mwe.mk4`

```
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local dom    = require "luaxml-domobject"

local function mwe_parsing(s)
      local obj = dom.parse(s)
      obj:traverse_elements(function(el)
      end)
      -- serialize the DOM object back to HTML
      return obj:serialize()
end

local process = filter {mwe_parsing}
Make:match("html$", process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

### Call to make4ht

The call to `make4ht` is

```
make4ht -u -c mwe.cfg mwe.tex
```

which results in HTML files, but the parsing error on the first file (`mwe.html`) has stopped parsing and subsequent build operations (in the above, `tidy`) of other files (`mwese1.html`)

```
parse_lg process file: mwe.html
...ive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:174: Unbalanced Tag (/mrow) [char=848]
```

### Note

I *know* what the problem is with `mwe.tex` and that it needs changing to `$(6)$`, but I am not in control of the source files I'm given, and part of the process is finding such errors. This question is something of a follow-up to [htlatex: tweaking the MathML output for numbers with more than one digit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413033/htlatex-tweaking-the-mathml-output-for-numbers-with-more-than-one-digit)

### The question

How can I customise `mwe.mk4` so that it gets through the parsing error in html files and continues with the build processes? Perhaps a check could be done to see if `dom.parse(s)` is successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `LuaXML` issues run-time error when it founds invalid XML structure. This is handled in `make4ht-domfilter`, but since you parse XML on your own, you must also handle the errors.

To catch errors, you can use the `pcall` function. The following build file needs development version of `make4ht`, because I found that `pcall` isn't available in build files by default. It should be fixed now.

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local dom    = require "luaxml-domobject"
local log = logging.new "build file"

local function mwe_parsing(s)
      local status, obj = pcall(function()
          return dom.parse(s)
      end)
      if not status then 
        log:warning("HTML parsing failed")
        log:warning(obj)
        return s 
      end
      obj:traverse_elements(function(el)
      end)
      -- serialize the DOM object back to HTML
      return obj:serialize()
end

local process = filter {mwe_parsing}
Make:match("html$", process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

The important part is this:

```
      local status, obj = pcall(function()
          return dom.parse(s)
      end)
      if not status then 
        log:warning("HTML parsing failed")
        log:warning(obj)
        return s 
      end
```

When `pcall` returns `false` status, the `obj` variable contains the error message. We can test for that, use built in `make4ht` logging to issue warning and return the original document. This will print the following warning:

```
 [WARNING] build file: HTML parsing failed
 [WARNING] build file: /home/michal/texmf/scripts/lua/LuaXML/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/mrow) [char=702]
```

Comment: Many thanks, as always, for this, that's really helpful. I think I had tried something similar to this, so I'm thinking I need to update my version of make4ht (looks like I'm on `v0.2g`). I'll update and report back. thanks so much

Comment: @cmhughes `pcall` didn't work in build files until today, so the update is necessary in this case. Version `0.2g` is really old, you may experience some substantial changes. Most important is that the CLI ouput is hidden by default, use `-a debug` option to see TeX output and other compilation messages.

Comment: That's very helpful, many thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated my texlive distribution to 2020, and have `V0.3e` of make4ht. Is there a way that I can access the develop version of `make4ht`?

Comment: @cmhughes you can install the development version from Github: https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/blob/master/INSTALL.md